# Remove erroneous javascript

Tags: sitefinity

Just fired up a test instance of Sitefinity. Seeing some injected JS. Searching for this JS reveals nothing relevant.

How do I remove this code? It is not in any of my templates:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/WebResource.axd?d=...;t=636632737400000000"></script>
```

And also:

```
StatsClient.LogVisit(..., ...)
```

I want no javascript on the page at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable the StatsClient code, you need to go to 
**Administration > Settings > Advanced > Statistics** and then select **None** for the **Page visit log mode** property. Restart the site.

Sitefinity is logging all page visits in case you want later to create personalization segments based on that.

As for the webresource.axd - it could be anything so you should inspect the contents of that file and then will see how to remove it.